# Javafx line color & letter 'q' to exit program

Tags: java, javafx

This part of my assignment works and is completed. I wanted to make additions to this though that I am struggling to figure out where to start. I wanted to change the color of each line movement. For example if I pressed up on the arrow key the line will be red, or to the right the line would be blue, etc.

I am also trying to make the program exit by clicking the letter q.

```
package derienzo15;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class DrawLines extends Application {

    Pane pane = new Pane();
    double width = 1000;
    double height = 1000;
    double cX = width / 2;
    double cY = height / 2;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch (e.getCode()) {
                case UP: moveUp(); break;
                case DOWN: moveDown(); break;
                case LEFT: moveLeft(); break;
                case RIGHT: moveRight(); break;
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, width, height));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Click to see position..");
        primaryStage.show();
        pane.requestFocus();
    }

    private void moveUp() {
        pane.getChildren().add(new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY - 10));
        cY -= 10;



    }

    private void moveDown() {
        pane.getChildren().add(new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY + 10));
        cY += 10;

    }
    private void moveLeft() {
        pane.getChildren().add(new Line(cX, cY, cX - 10, cY));
        cX -= 10;

    }
    private void moveRight() {
        pane.getChildren().add(new Line(cX, cY, cX + 10, cY));
        cX += 10;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quit, you need to add another `case` into your `pane.setOnKeyPressed` `switch` statement.

So:

```
pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
    switch (e.getCode()) {
        case UP: moveUp(); break;
        case DOWN: moveDown(); break;
        case LEFT: moveLeft(); break;
        case RIGHT: moveRight(); break;
        case Q: primaryStage.close(); break;
    }
});
```

To change the line colour you have to modify your `functions` fired when you push arrow keys. To change a line colour, you can use [setStroke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setStroke-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-).

```
private void moveUp() {
    Line line = new Line(cX, cY, cX, cY - 10);
    line.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    pane.getChildren().add(line);
    cY -= 10;
}
```

You will note I put the line object creation on its own line, so you can execute the `setStroke` method.